# Sci-fi TV series about medicine/virology/pathogen/germ warfare investigation

Tags: story-identification, tv, soft-sci-fi, virus

Unfortunately, the only details I am really sure of are the specific scenes I mention below. The rest I am quite hazy on.

IIRC it aired sometime in the mid to late 90s (maybe even early 2000s?) and it was on one of the major networks (NBC?) as opposed to a cable network like SciFi/Syfy. The show was about a team that goes around investigating various biological threats (diseases, germ warfare, etc.) They have a whole "hot room" type mobile lab with all the requisite bells and whistles (blinky light computers, biohazard suits, etc.)

In one episode, they were investigating some sort of medical treatment or drug or something that had the unintended side effect of causing the calcium in peoples' bones to leach away at an alarming rate. Peoples' bones started suddenly breaking while they were out walking, exercising, etc. In one scene a woman was swimming and her bones started disintegrating while she was in the pool, causing her to drown. In another episode, one of the main characters became infected with some sort of disease or pathogen or something that caused them to develop a ridiculously high runaway fever, requiring them to cool him or her down in a ice water bath of some sort.

Comment: It seems barely possible that this could be referencing the TV show *Fringe* .. the episodes ["Concentrate and Ask Again"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentrate_and_Ask_Again) (bones turn into dust because of a blue powder) and ["What Lies Below"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Lies_Below) (hemorragic fever that also makes people want to spread it) would be relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Highly likely that you are looking for an episode of a TV series called The Burning Zone. Produced in the wake of the stratospheric success of The X-Files this only ran for one series in either 1996 or 1997.

It was about a team assembled to handle medical/biological emergencies and episode 13 titled Death Song specifically dealt with deaths arising from massive bone loss.

You can read about the show on wikipedia here... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Burning_Zone

and see a promo for the show on youtube here...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Burning_Zone

The particular episode I thing you are referring to does not appear to be on you tube.

The show matches your timescale and aired on a chanel I think called UPN. I am british so may be mistaken about this detail.

Considering your time frame you may be conflating episodes of the X-files with this show. The plot you describe with a high runaway fever is reminiscent of an ongoing arc of stories in The X-files in which characters exposed to an alien pathogen must be kept in ice water otherwise they would likely die. The two hander from the second season of The X-files titled Colony/End Game is a good fit for this. Check out this wikipedia page for a synopsis...

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_X-Files_episodes#Season_3_(1995–96)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_X-Files_episodes#Season_3_(1995%E2%80%9396))

Comment: That is exactly the show I was thinking of! Thank you! Accepted.

Comment: glad to be of service!